# How to restrict user input?

Tags: c#

I want to restrict user input, so he can only type in 28,29,30 or 31.

I know that there is a way to do it by checking if the input is in an array of valid dates/day. Could someone explain me how can I do a check? For example if

int[] days = new int[4] {28, 29, 30, 31};

How can I do validation that will check if what user inputted is inside the array? What conditions should I set? I don't have a code to show since I do not know how to write that type of validation. If there is no way to do it how can restrict user with if statement that will restrict him to only these 4 numbers?

My code so far looks like that:

```
    int GetDaysInMonth()
    {
        const int MinDaysInMonth = 28;
        const int MaxDaysInMonth = 31;

        Console.WriteLine("How many days there are in your chosen month? [it needs to be 28, 30 or 31]");
        userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        while (!int.TryParse(userInput, out daysInMonth) || daysInMonth > MaxDaysInMonth || daysInMonth < MinDaysInMonth)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong input! Remember it needs to be 28, 30 or 31");
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        return daysInMonth;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What code do you have that you're trying to limit input on? Is this for a console app? Web app? Winforms app?

Comment: Console application

Comment: I have added piece of code, that I want to validate as I explained above.

Comment: Looks fine to me, whats your question?

Comment: My question is that I want to do validate that so it will put restriction to only 4 number. 28,29,30,31 <--- everything except that should be invalid.

Comment: **Based on your code message**: Add a check to make sure its not 29 or use an array of allowed numbers and validate that the number falls inside that list. **Based on your comment**: the code does exactly what your comment states.

Comment: While I am at it I have another question, If I leave my method 'int void method name' is it correct formating? or is there a need for public,private or internal?

Comment: If you do not supply an access modifier to a class member the default access modifier is private. To make your intent clear you should include an access modifier though but it is not required, this last part on that you should include it is just opinion.

Comment: Well haha to be honest I did not saw that my code is actually doing what I wanted haha xD My bad sorry, but I learnt how to check if the input is inside array of valid inputs which is what I wanted from the start. It reduced my code even if it is only by 1 condition. (1 codition less in while loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to check if an input is in an array of valid inputs you could use the `.Contains()` method.

```
public static bool IsValid(int input, int[] validInputs)
{
    return validInputs.Contains(input);
}
```

You could use it like below:

```
int input = 28;
int[] validInputs = new[] { 28, 29, 30, 31 };

bool result = IsValid(input, validInputs); //result is `true`
```

Comment: I got it, Thank you.